Need to compute distances between each of 60,000 coordinates
I am working on a correlative study in Python that needs a matrix of distances between each pair of coordinates in a data set with 60,000 data points. I have attempted vectorization, and using geopandas, but the problem with geopandas is that to run the distance function, I need the x and y data in repeating lists (the x data repeating the set of 60,000 towers and the y repeating each coordinate 60,000 times in a row)  making each list 3.6e9 values long, and my computer runs out of memory before this is completed, or when I try to run it on a remote desktop at my school, it takes more than half an hour and I haven't been able to run it successfully. Here is the code I am running:
#Florida Tower Matrix 
#take coordinates of Florida towers
#CHECK THE LAT/LONG order 
import geojson
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point
features = []
with open("/Users/katcn/Desktop/Spring 2024/Research/PleaseWork.geojson") as f:
   gj = geojson.load(f)

for i in range(59629):
   features.append(gj['features'][i]["geometry"]['coordinates'])


#OR make the X matrix all in one column 
#make the Y matrix repeat each value 59000 times 
longitude = []
latitude = []
for i in range(len(features)):
   for j in range(len(features)):
       longitude.append(features[j][0])
   for k in range(len(features)):
       latitude.append(features[i][0])


dict = {"longitude" : longitude, "latitude" : latitude}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
dict2 = {"longitude" : longitude, "latitude" : latitude}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict2)
#calculate distance between two towers 
geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df.longitude, df.latitude)]
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, crs={'init': 'epsg:4326'}, geometry=geometry)

geometry2 = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df2.longitude, df2.latitude)]
gdf2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df2, crs={'init': 'epsg:4326'}, geometry=geometry2)

distances = gdf.geometry.distance(gdf2.geometry)

print(distances)

Any suggestions for how to approach this problem differently to make it a more reasonable run-time would be great.

This answer is to solve the issue that immediately follows, namely saving the results you obtain to a csv-file. Given the shear size of the data, pd.to_csv() is not the way to go.
Here, I build on the previous solution by computing the distance matrix, note that the matrix actually is sparse since the distance between xand y is the same as the distance betweeen y and x (so the matrix is triangular.
I create the dataframe by adding the points (lat, long). Then, using polar I tranform the pandas dataframe to a polar dataframe and finally save it:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time

def haversine(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(np.radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])
    dlon = lon2 - lon1 
    dlat = lat2 - lat1 
    a = np.sin(dlat/2)**2 + np.cos(lat1) * np.cos(lat2) * np.sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(a)) 
    r = 6371  
    return c * r

np.random.seed(42)
latitudes = np.random.uniform(low=25.0, high=49.0, size=10000)
longitudes = np.random.uniform(low=-125.0, high=-66.0, size=10000)
coords = np.column_stack((latitudes, longitudes))

start_time = time.time()

n = coords.shape[0]
dist_matrix = np.zeros((n, n))
for i in range(n):
    dist_matrix[i, :] = haversine(coords[i, 0], coords[i, 1], coords[:, 0], coords[:, 1])

end_time = time.time()
elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
print("Distance matrix computed in {:.2f} seconds".format(elapsed_time))
print("Shape of the distance matrix:", dist_matrix.shape)

point_labels = [f"Point {i}" for i in range(n)]
dist_df = pd.DataFrame(dist_matrix, index=point_labels, columns=point_labels)


distance = dist_df.loc['Point 0', 'Point 1']
print(f"Distance from Point 0 to Point 1: {distance} km")

lat_lon_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([latitudes, longitudes], names=['Latitude', 'Longitude'])
dist_df.index = lat_lon_index
dist_df.columns = lat_lon_index

lat_from, lon_from = latitudes[0], longitudes[0]  
lat_to, lon_to = latitudes[1], longitudes[1]
distance = dist_df.loc[(lat_from, lon_from), (lat_to, lon_to)]
print(f"Distance from ({lat_from}, {lon_from}) to ({lat_to}, {lon_to}): {distance} km")

Now the dist_df looks like this

To save it to a csv just do this:
dist_df_reset = dist_df.reset_index()

polars_df = pl.from_pandas(dist_df_reset)

polars_df.write_csv('polars_distance_matrix.csv')

The file will be:

IMPORTANT NOTE: This will be much faster, but you cannot hope for it to take very little time with that many points

Okay I tried this on my Windows desktop, and I am having memory problems since I am only a user and the allocation is not large enough to reindex the dataframe (even though I checked at it around 33 GB. I got rid of the reindex to see if the CSV would even save, and it ran out of malloc memory, which I believe is the memory from the polars module. I tried to then run it on my PC, but there was an issue with Mac OS running Python under rosetta dependencies for the polars package, which I can try to fix.

You could save it as a dat file. Why do you want to save it as a csv file?

I just need it in any file format that I can import to MATLAB. But, any file format that isn't CSV silently stops running without accomplishing anything. I tried to just run the python file through MATLAB so exporting wouldn't be necessary, but I couldn't get MATLAB to run the numpy that's used to make the distance matrix.

You actually do not need to use geopandas distance function to do this. Basically, the only thing you need is scipy. Start with putting your coordinates in an array:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import geojson
from scipy.spatial import distance

with open("/Users/katcn/Desktop/Spring 2024/Research/PleaseWork.geojson") as f:
    gj = geojson.load(f)

coords = np.array([feature["geometry"]["coordinates"] for feature in gj['features']])
dist_matrix = distance.cdist(coords, coords, 'euclidean')
dist_df = pd.DataFrame(dist_matrix)
print(dist_df)

Since you did not provide data, I created a sample dataset with Continental USA points (here 60 000 points from KKey West, FL to Canadian borderey and West Coast to East Coast):
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.spatial import distance
import time

np.random.seed(42)


latitudes = np.random.uniform(low=25.0, high=49.0, size=60000)  
longitudes = np.random.uniform(low=-125.0, high=-66.0, size=60000) 
coords = np.column_stack((latitudes, longitudes))

start_time = time.time()

dist_matrix = distance.cdist(coords, coords, 'euclidean')

end_time = time.time()
elapsed_time = end_time - start_time

print("Distance matrix computed in {:.2f} seconds".format(elapsed_time))
print("Shape of the distance matrix:", dist_matrix.shape)


Which take
Distance matrix computed in 185.64 seconds
Shape of the distance matrix: (60000, 60000)

So roughly 3 minutes.
 UPDATE: USING GEODESIC DISTANCE
This works but takes along time:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from geopy.distance import geodesic
import time

np.random.seed(42)

latitudes = np.random.uniform(low=25.0, high=49.0, size=60000)
longitudes = np.random.uniform(low=-125.0, high=-66.0, size=60000)

coords = list(zip(latitudes, longitudes))

def geodesic_distance_matrix(coords):
    n = len(coords)
    dist_matrix = np.zeros((n, n))
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i+1, n): 
            dist_matrix[i, j] = geodesic(coords[i], coords[j]).meters
            dist_matrix[j, i] = dist_matrix[i, j]
    return dist_matrix

start_time = time.time()

dist_matrix = geodesic_distance_matrix(coords)

end_time = time.time()
elapsed_time = end_time - start_time

print("Distance matrix computed in {:.2f} seconds".format(elapsed_time))
print("Shape of the distance matrix:", dist_matrix.shape)


Another appraoach is to use haversine in the following manner:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time

def haversine(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(np.radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])

    dlon = lon2 - lon1 
    dlat = lat2 - lat1 
    a = np.sin(dlat/2)**2 + np.cos(lat1) * np.cos(lat2) * np.sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(a)) 
    r = 6371  
    return c * r

np.random.seed(42)
latitudes = np.random.uniform(low=25.0, high=49.0, size=60000)
longitudes = np.random.uniform(low=-125.0, high=-66.0, size=60000)
coords = np.column_stack((latitudes, longitudes))

start_time = time.time()

n = coords.shape[0]
dist_matrix = np.zeros((n, n))
for i in range(n):
    dist_matrix[i, :] = haversine(coords[i, 0], coords[i, 1], coords[:, 0], coords[:, 1])

end_time = time.time()
elapsed_time = end_time - start_time

print("Distance matrix computed in {:.2f} seconds".format(elapsed_time))
print("Shape of the distance matrix:", dist_matrix.shape)


which returns
Distance matrix computed in 463.75 seconds
Shape of the distance matrix: (60000, 60000)

so more than double the time of the euclidean distance.
array([[   0.        , 1683.78776508, 1717.22879531, ..., 1706.77761313,
        3857.52001651, 1579.36733204],
       [1683.78776508,    0.        , 2008.58039812, ..., 2813.5398641 ,
        4379.29512353, 2340.45973263],
       [1717.22879531, 2008.58039812,    0.        , ..., 1151.61134582,
        2399.40193517,  560.14519709],
       ...,
       [1706.77761313, 2813.5398641 , 1151.61134582, ...,    0.        ,
        2244.42005933,  593.632848  ],
       [3857.52001651, 4379.29512353, 2399.40193517, ..., 2244.42005933,
           0.        , 2291.13872501],
       [1579.36733204, 2340.45973263,  560.14519709, ...,  593.632848  ,
        2291.13872501,    0.        ]])

the dimension is kilometers here. If you want miles you'll need to change
 r = 6371 

to
r = 3956


This works great and runs in about a minute for me. I'm wondering since I do need the output in meters, and the coordinates are lat/long if I should use of the the different distance calculations Scipy offers for a more accurate result than Euclidian? Do you know what the units of the euclidean output are?

Do you mean geodesic distance?

It is fully posssible, but the very nature of the geodesic distance means that with 60 000 points, you'll have 3.6 billion comapirsons to make. Let me look into another way.

Yes I mean the geodesic distance sorry, since the coordinates are for power line towers in Florida, I think geodesic would be better than the Euclidian

@KatNeumann Check the updates.

If it is what you hoped for, don't forget to mark the answer as accepted so it is removed from the list of questions without answers.

Sorry for the delay, it runs in 10 minutes for me which is great, but I have had issues trying to get the data into a csv cause its taking too long, I'll run it again and have it show me the variables before I try saving it so I can mark this as answered

@KatNeumann .csv is not the best file type for such amount of data, try .parquet or just numpy .npz

@dankal444 Okay, I spent the last two days trying parquet and npz and mat cause I need this to be importable to Matlab, but any file format I use doesn't work. I'm using VS code, and I've been testing the write-to-file functions and I can get small matrices to write, but the distance matrix breaks without writing anything to the files. I am not sure why this is happening since my debugger isn't throwing an error, the file run just dies. The only thing I have gotten to write is to CSV, but it took like 5 hours to run a third of the matrix. Do you know any ways to speed up writing to a CSV

@KatNeumann Maybe some of your problems were file-size/RAM related and all you need is split saved data into parts? polars package was fast when it comes to read/write csv, worth a try. Matlab should read parquet files, you pay for this software so you can contact authors why it isn't working. My guess is file is too large

@KatNeumann What data are you trying to get to a csv? What transformations do you do with the ditance matrix before attempting to send it to csv?

@KatNeumann I have proposed an alternative answer to your question. If it solves you entire problem, do mark it as accepted answer so the question no longer remains unanswered.
